# Distribute a python package which requires a C++ library

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging, python-packaging

I have a python package which **needs** a C++ library to work. The library is loaded with `ctypes.CDLL` and used by the package internally. What are the different ways I can package and distribute this python package, so that a simple `pip install my-package` command will result in a fully working package, including this C++ library?

For now, my approach (which feels a bit ugly) is to include a folder `lib` which contains the C++ library for different platforms: `*20.04_amd64.so`, `*22.04_amd64.so`, `*amd64.dylib`, `*arm64.dylib`, `*amd64.dll`, `*i386.dll`. This folder combine to some python logic loads the correct C++ lib for the platform on which the package is installed.

The folder `lib` is included in the distributed files with the following lines in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"my-package.lib" = ["*"]
```

Any better ideas?